# Vue.js why my watcher is not working?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

After setting a watcher on an input data , I am trying to display both old value and new value, but they are both undefined... what could be wrong ?

see [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/erwin16/pen/PBwZYN?editors=1111)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container mt-1 grid-list-xl">
      <v-layout row wrap justify-space-around>
        <v-flex d-flex sm6 md6>
          <v-layout row wrap>
            <v-flex d-flex>
              <v-card class="flexcard" dark tile flat>
                <v-card-title class="card__title justify-center">PROFILE</v-card-title>
                <form @submit.prevent="onUpdateProfile()">
                <v-card-text class="card__text grow">
                  <v-text-field  @keyup.native="setDirty" placeholder="Enter your new email address" :readonly="isReadOnly" label="Email" v-model="user.email" prepend-icon="email">
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-tooltip  v-if="isReadOnly" right>
                      <v-btn  @click="onEditProfile" icon class="primary" large slot="activator">
                       <v-icon color="white">edit</v-icon>
                        </v-btn>
                        <span>EDIT</span>
                  </v-tooltip>                                                                                          
                <v-btn v-if="isProfileEditing" round @click="cancel()">CANCEL</v-btn>
                <v-btn v-if="isProfileDirty" round color="primary" type="submit">UPDATE</v-btn>
                </v-card-action>
                </form>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-flex>
     </v-layout>
      </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted () {
    this.user.email = 'john.doe@example.com'
  },
  data: () => ({
     user: {
      email: ''
    },
    cache: {
      user: {
        email: ''
      }
    },
    editIcon: {
      email: 'edit'
    },
    isProfileEditing: false,
    isProfileDirty: false,
    isReadOnly: true
  }),
  watch: {
    user: function (newUser, oldUser) {
      console.log('Old User Email: ', oldUser.email)
      console.log('New User Email: ', newUser.email)
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  methods: {
    onUpdateProfile () {
      console.log('UPDATE PROFILE: ', this.user.emaill)
    },
    onEditProfile () {
      this.isProfileEditing = true
      this.isReadOnly = false
      this.cache.user.email = this.user.email
      this.user.email = ''
    },
    cancel () {
      this.isProfileEditing = false
      this.isProfileDirty = false
      if (!this.isReadOnly) {
       this.isReadOnly = true
       this.user.email = this.cache.user.email
      }
    },
    setDirty () {
      this.isProfileDirty = true
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: ```console.log('UPDATE PROFILE: ', this.user.emaill)``` you trying to access property ```emaill``` here. But should ```email```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To listen to changes for a property in an object you should add deep watcher. To do so add `deep: true` property to your watcher.

```
watch: {
  user: {
    handler: function (newUser, oldUser) {
      console.log('Old User Email: ', oldUser.email)
      console.log('New User Email: ', newUser.email)
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Here is the [updated pen](https://codepen.io/rvams1993/pen/ajzNJZ?editors=1011#0)

But if you are trying to make use of the `oldUser` , then the watcher cannot help you bacause:

> Note: when mutating (rather than replacing) an Object or an Array, the old value will be the same as new value because they reference the same Object/Array. Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value.

That's the reason you see the same value for both `newUser` and `oldUser` when `user.email` is updated.

Reference - [vm.watch API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)

Comment: Kishna .   Thanks for this feedback ... I forgot it... god point regarding old value ... !!

Comment: @erwin Yup they are equal because in javascript objects are passed by reference. Both `newUser` and `oldUser` refer the same object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to watch for changes nested data you have to set `deep` option of watcher. However you can't access an old data in handler as Vue doesn’t keep a copy of the pre-mutate value of objects. In your case, the code of your `watch` object should look like this below:

```js
watch: {
  user: {
    handler: function (newUser) {
      console.log('New User Email: ', newUser.email)
    },
    deep: true
  }
}
```

Reference: [Vue's official API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)

Comment: Thanks for feedback ... however Vamsi Krishna answer is actually more detailed ...  useful info about old and new values !